# Delphi CGI WebService - Digital Certificates

Tags: web-services, apache, delphi, cgi, capicom

I Have a delphi 7 CGI webService (in windows XP but windows 7 is not out of the table) application in witch i need to access digital certificate to sign a XML document.

I Have imported CApicom_TLB and successfuly got to instanciate the certificate, but with some problems...

the apache server that runs my app runs it with a different windows user in wich i installed the certificate, wich leaves the Certificate Store empty when i query with CAPICOM_CURRENT_USER_STORE flag. I worked-arround it by installing the A1 certificate (Pfx with privatekey) in the local machine (Via MMC console, add new snap-in) and accessing the Certificate Store with the CAPICOM_LOCAL_MACHINE_STORE flag. I get the certificate (i can read its serial number, friendly name, valid to date) but when i try to sign a document, i get "Key Pair does not exist" error.

The same code works (successfuly sign XML) in a normal APP (Not-cgi) with the same PFx.

Code i use to get the certificate:

```
Store := CoStore.Create;
 Store.Open(CAPICOM_LOCAL_MACHINE_STORE, CAPICOM_STORE_NAME, CAPICOM_STORE_OPEN_MAXIMUM_ALLOWED);

 Certs := Store.Certificates as ICertificates2;
 for i:= 1 to Certs.Count do
  begin
   Cert := IInterface(Certs.Item[i]) as ICertificate2;
   if Cert.SerialNumber = FNumeroSerie
    then begin
     if DFeUtil.EstaVazio(NumCertCarregado)
      then NumCertCarregado := Cert.SerialNumber;

     if CertStoreMem = nil
      then begin
       CertStoreMem := CoStore.Create;
       CertStoreMem.Open(CAPICOM_MEMORY_STORE, 'Memoria', CAPICOM_STORE_OPEN_MAXIMUM_ALLOWED);
       CertStoreMem.Add(Cert);
      end;
```

Then i use the CertStoreMem to sign usign the folowing

```
OleCheck(IDispatch(Certificado.PrivateKey).QueryInterface(IPrivateKey,PrivateKey));
 xmldsig.store := CertStoreMem;

 dsigKey := xmldsig.createKeyFromCSP(PrivateKey.ProviderType, PrivateKey.ProviderName, PrivateKey.ContainerName, 0);
```

The error (Key pair) is in the last line of code.

There are two approaches: Make the CGI application read the certificate in the same user that installed it (code that works in non-cgi) OR make this work-arround with the localmachine-installed certificate work without key error.

If anyone could help would be much appreciated

Comment: Your best bet is to hope that Eugene Mayevski from ElDos sees this question and helps you out.  http://stackoverflow.com/users/47961/eugene-mayevski-eldos-corp

Answer (score 0):

If it is an issue with user authentication, and you have (total) control over the server, I would consider wrapping the signing bit in a Active X library, and adding it to a COM+ package; using the Component Services you can control activation and authentification so it runs with impersonation in a separate dllhost.exe

Comment: Its not about user autentication. I Use the certificate to sign an XML file... but thanks

Comment: Well, authentication might not be the right word, but I mean anything related to the user profile data such as the private certificate store.